# FirebaseMessagingException: Error while calling FCM backend service

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send the fem notification :

```
MulticastMessage message = MulticastMessage.builder()
            .putData("score", "850")
            .putData("time", "2:45")
            .addAllTokens(requestDTO.getTokenIds())
            .build();


        try {
            firebaseInstance.sendMulticast(message);
        } catch (FirebaseMessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now this code is working from one server but when same jar i am running on different server, it is showing the exception message :

```
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Error while calling FCM backend service
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.sendAll(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:141)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$2.execute(FirebaseMessaging.java:293)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$2.execute(FirebaseMessaging.java:290)
    at com.google.firebase.internal.CallableOperation.call(CallableOperation.java:36)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.sendAll(FirebaseMessaging.java:183)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.sendMulticast(FirebaseMessaging.java:252)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.sendMulticast(FirebaseMessaging.java:227)
    at com.demo.notiifcationsender.sender.firebase.FirebaseService.send(FirebaseService.java:89)
    at com.demo.notiifcationsender.consumers.KafkaConsumerListeners.listen(KafkaConsumerListeners.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:248)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cde8c01d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.messaging.MessageListenerMethodInterceptor.invoke(TraceMessagingAutoConfiguration.java:256)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3c289c2b.onMessage(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1083)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1025)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:893)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:748)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:259)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.batch.BatchRequest.execute(BatchRequest.java:241)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.sendBatchRequest(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:168)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.sendAll(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:137)
    ... 34 more
```

What i am doing wrong. All the config are with the code while compilation.

Same jar is able to deliver the notification from one server but unable to deliver it from other server(2-3 different server).

Are these server blocked or what? How should I debug those?

Firebase config :

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "my-pro",
  "private_key_id": "bbbbbbbbbBbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nPRIVATE JET CINTEBT\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-cg2zu@sabncd.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "12121212121212121212121",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-cg2zu%sabncd.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Firebase Instance Creator

```
@Configuration
public class FirebaseInstanceCreator {

    @Bean
    public FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging() throws IOException {
        ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("serviceAccount.json");
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions   .Builder()
                                                      .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(classPathResource.getInputStream()))
                                                      .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        return FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the firebase config in your in your Java Server.

Comment: Not the config file but where you are creating firebase options and initializing Firebase Instance. FCM depends upon service account credentials it should work on any server

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having the same issue.